# How to extract characters based on content of each row in a list?

Tags: r, list

I have a list like this:

```
list1 = list(data.frame("Gene" = c("A","B","C","D","E"), "Sample" = "S1"),
             data.frame("Gene" = c("B","C","D","F","G"), "Sample" = "S2"),
             data.frame("Gene" = c("A","C","D","E","F"), "Sample" = "S3"))

names(list1) = c("S1","S2","S3")
```

I would like to report which `Sample` are present for each `Gene` in the entire `list1`. For example

```
$A
"S1","S3"

$B
"S1","S2"

$C
"S1","S2","S3"

$D
"S1","S2","S3"

$E
"S1","S3"

$F
"S2","S3"

$G
"S2"
```

There are no duplicated `Gene` within the list, but there are common `Gene` between the list and for each `Gene`, I wanted to find out which `Sample` in which it is present. Could someone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use `do.call(rbind,..)` to make the list into one dataframe then `unstack` the dataframe:

```
unstack(do.call(rbind,list1),Sample~Gene)
$A
[1] "S1" "S3"

$B
[1] "S1" "S2"

$C
[1] "S1" "S2" "S3"

$D
[1] "S1" "S2" "S3"

$E
[1] "S1" "S3"

$F
[1] "S2" "S3"

$G
[1] "S2"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer the output in more of a `tibble` or `data.frame` format you can use:

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(list1) %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  summarise(Samples = toString(Sample))

#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   Gene  Samples   
#>   <chr> <chr>     
#> 1 A     S1, S3    
#> 2 B     S1, S2    
#> 3 C     S1, S2, S3
#> 4 D     S1, S2, S3
#> 5 E     S1, S3    
#> 6 F     S2, S3    
#> 7 G     S2
```

Or you could `nest` them for further processing:

```
bind_rows(list1) %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  nest()

#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   Gene  data            
#>   <chr> <list>          
#> 1 A     <tibble [2 x 1]>
#> 2 B     <tibble [2 x 1]>
#> 3 C     <tibble [3 x 1]>
#> 4 D     <tibble [3 x 1]>
#> 5 E     <tibble [2 x 1]>
#> 6 F     <tibble [2 x 1]>
#> 7 G     <tibble [1 x 1]>
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `split` from `base R` after `rbind`ing the `list` elements

```
with(do.call(rbind, list1), split(Sample, Gene))
#$A
#[1] "S1" "S3"

#$B
#[1] "S1" "S2"

#$C
#[1] "S1" "S2" "S3"

#$D
#[1] "S1" "S2" "S3"

#$E
#[1] "S1" "S3"

#$F
#[1] "S2" "S3"

#$G
#[1] "S2"
```